# integrating a shopping cart, not the other way around

Tags: shopping-cart

ZEN Cart seems to be able to do anything I could possibly ever want, but seems a bit bloated (for me) and more importantly - it's design process seems unbearable. I don't want to have reform a default design, I have my website design completed other than the shopping cart related items. I want to be able to add them in, working the shopping cart into my site, rather than the other way around.  I need a shopping cart that can handle discounts and inventories and such, and of course as small as possible.  Can anyone help recommend an OS cart that will allow this?

Thank so much for your time and suggestions!!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't ask for any platform/languages in particular, so.

If you're using Django, then [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) looks to be an attractive option.  Even if you're not, it might be fairly trivial to mash in, depending on how your site is set up.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the cart that Google Checkout provides — is a JS system , easily themed with CSS (if you can learn to accept the !important tag), but [SimpleCartJs](http://www.thewojogroup.com/2008/10/simplecartjs-paypal-e-commerce-in-minutes/) is as easy as it comes, and it's for PayPal. Re-styles easily and it's pretty elegant.